# oracle procedure ORA-06550, PLS_00103

Tags: oracle, shell, ora-06550, pls-00103

I have a procedure defined as:

```
 PROCEDURE Import_Invoice 
  (     as_Directory_Name_Invoice_Data in varchar2,
        as_File_Name_Invoice_Data in varchar2,
        as_Directory_Name_Invoice_Log in varchar2,
        al_processid out number, 
        al_errnum out number,
        as_errstr out varchar2 ) IS

 begin
           al_processid := 123;
           al_errnum := 2;
           as_errstr := 'sfs';
end;
```

when I execute the procedure from a shell script as:

```
#! /bin/ksh
::::::::::::
OUTVAL=`sqlplus -s usr/passwd@ora_instance <<EOF
264 whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
265 set pagesize 0
266 set feed off
267 set echo off
268 set serveroutput on
269 DECLARE
270 var al_errnum number,
271 var as_errstr varchar2,
272 var al_processid number,
273 BEGIN
274 execute Import_Invoice('INVOICE_INBOUND_DAT_DIR','INVOICE_apvend_daily.dat','INVOICE_INBOUND_LOG_DIR', al_processid, al_errnum, as_errstr );
275 END
276 /
277 EOF`

::::::
```

OUTVAL returned as:

```
OUTVAL=var al_errnum number, CAMS_INVOICE_20180802_120830.DAT INVOICE_apvend_daily.dat ERROR at line 2: ORA-06550: line 2, column 15: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMBER" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
```

**I can't find what is wrong.**

Thanks you for your suggestions.

**Update:**
*as @dandarc suggested, I change the calling code to:*

```
OUTVAL=`sqlplus -s usr/passwd@ora_instance <<EOF
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
set pagesize 0
set feed off
set echo off
set serveroutput on
var al_errnum number
var as_errstr varchar2(1000)
var al_processid number
BEGIN
execute Import_Invoice('INVOICE_INBOUND_DAT_DIR','INVOICE_apvend_daily.dat','INVOICE_INBOUND_LOG_DIR', :al_processid, :al_errnum, :as_errstr );
END
/
EOF`
```

I get this error:

```
OUTVAL=execute Import_Invoice('INVOICE_INBOUND_DAT_DIR','INVOICE_apvend_daily.dat','INVOICE_INBOUND_LOG_DIR', :al_processid, :al_errnum, :as_errstr ); CAMS_INVOICE_20180802_120830.DAT INVOICE_apvend_daily.dat ERROR at line 2: ORA-06550: line 2, column 9: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IMPORT_INVOICE" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; immediate The symbol ":=" was substituted for "IMPORT_INVOICE" to continue. ORA-06550: line 3, column 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In your script declaration section:

```
269 DECLARE
270 var al_errnum number,
271 var as_errstr varchar2,
272 var al_processid number,
```

Should be:

```
269 DECLARE
270  al_errnum number;
271  as_errstr varchar2;
272  al_processid number;
```

PL/SQL doesn't need var, and each line should end with a semi-colon there.

That would clear the error, but you probably want a script that looks something like this:

```
#! /bin/ksh
::::::::::::
OUTVAL=`sqlplus -s usr/passwd@ora_instance <<EOF
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
set pagesize 0
set feed off
set echo off
set serveroutput on
var al_errnum number
var as_errstr varchar2(20)
var al_processid number
BEGIN
Import_Invoice('INVOICE_INBOUND_DAT_DIR','INVOICE_apvend_daily.dat','INVOICE_INBOUND_LOG_DIR', :al_processid, :al_errnum, :as_errstr );
275 END
276 /
277 EOF`

::::::
```

Declare sqlplus variables, then pass those to your procedure. Presumably, you'd check those variables later in your script.

Comment: I would think that the numbers at the beginning of each line of the here doc would cause an error. ???

Comment: @dandarc thank you for the quick response, I change my calling code in the sell file as you suggested, then the OYTVAL becaome: `OUTVAL=SP2-0552: Bind variable "AS_ERRSTR" not declared.`

Comment: @bob Javis the numbers are not real. when you in the `vi` editor, type `:set nu`, the ditory will add the numbers at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Did you only change the call to the procedure? Notice the "Declare" statement is also gone in the example.

Comment: @dandarc I forgot to remove the DECLARE. Now this is what I have:

Comment: Didn't even notice that - you don't say "execute" in PL/SQL either when you want to run a stored procedure - just remove execute from your script. The over-arching problem you're having is you're mixing SQL*Plus commands and PL/SQL commands. Your first version had SQL*Plus variable declarations in a PL/SQL code block - on these scripts you've gotta know what language you're writing in where.